# Spring Boot @RestController and @Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a @Controller:

```
@Controller("/")
public class GreetingController {

  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public String get() {
    return "greeting";
  }
}
```

Also a @RestController:

```
@RestController("/test")
public class TestRest {

  @RequestMapping()
  public List<TestDTO> get() {
    List<TestDTO> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
    dtos.add(new TestDTO("value1","value2"));
    dtos.add(new TestDTO("value1","value2"));
    return dtos;
  }
}
```

The @Controller works correctly, and serves a static HTML page at `src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html`

But the @RestController does not work, all I get are 404s.

If I move the method from the @RestController into the @Controller and add a @ResponseBody annotation, it then starts working.

How can I have the controllers as different classes?

Comment: This smells.  Your naming your `Controller` `"/"`, and your `RestController` `"/test"`.  I believe both of them would glom onto `/` in this context.  What happens if you put a `RequestMapping("/")` in your `Controller` and add below the `RestController` annotation your `RequestMapping` of `"/test"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RestController` and `@Controller` do not take the path to the resource as a parameter.  Perhaps try something along the lines of...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRest {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<TestDTO> get() {
    List<TestDTO> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
    dtos.add(new TestDTO("value1","value2"));
    dtos.add(new TestDTO("value1","value2"));
    return dtos;
  }
}
```

Comment: could use `@getMapping` instead

Answer (score 0):

You question itself has the answers, for the RESTController to work, you would need to have a @ResponseBody because, for all REST calls, there needs to be response body to return the data.
I hope adding @ResponseBody alone will solve the problem.

Comment: no. using `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` eliminates the need of adding the `@ResponseBody`